# upgrading/installing programs

Tags: default-programs

I am having some difficulty getting python 3.5.2 to work. I have followed the method in the readme file but it does not seem to allow me access. I can only access the default 2.7 version on Ubuntu 16.04. should I move the compressed file to the usr folder from the download folder before extracting the files and installing?

Comment: You already have python3 in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: do `python3 -V` to see its installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes by default with Python 2.7 and Python 3.5.2.
To make sure that you have Python 3.5.2. installed, run
`$ python3 -V` If the response is `Python 3.5.2+`, then it means that you have it installed.

Whenever you wish to use Python 3.5.2, just run the `python3` command instead of running `python`.